# `Zlib::GzipFile::Error` when using `vcr` with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm doing [Railscast #291 Testing with VCR (Pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr?view=asciicast).

I want to use rspec with `vcr`. The tests without vcr pass with this code.

```
# spec/requests/zip_code_lookup_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe "ZipCodeLookup" do
  it "show Beverly Hills given 90210" do
      visit root_path
      fill_in "zip_code", with: "90210"
      click_on "Lookup"
      page.should have_content("Beverly Hills")
  end
end
```

And as the tutorial I've put code in a `VCR.use_cassette` like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "ZipCodeLookup" do
  it "show Beverly Hills given 90210" do
    VCR.use_cassette "zip_code/90210" do
      visit root_path
      fill_in "zip_code", with: "90210"
      click_on "Lookup"
      page.should have_content("Beverly Hills")
    end
  end
end
```

And created this file:

```
# spec/support/vcr.rb
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join("spec", "vcr")
  c.stub_with :fakeweb
end
```

According to the tutorial the rspec test should pass with this, but it fails with this error:

```
  1) ZipCodeLookup show Beverly Hills given 90210
     Failure/Error: click_on "Lookup"
     Zlib::GzipFile::Error:
       not in gzip format
     # ./app/models/zip_code.rb:6:in `initialize'
     # ./app/controllers/zip_code_lookup_controller.rb:3:in `new'
     # ./app/controllers/zip_code_lookup_controller.rb:3:in `index'
     # ./spec/requests/zip_code_lookup_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/zip_code_lookup_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have no idea why `gzip` appears here and not in the rest of the rails project.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same issue: the **fakeweb** gem is now [deprecated in VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/238), use **webmock** instead

in your Gemfile, replace

```
gem 'fakeweb'
```

by

```
gem 'webmock'
```

re-bundle, and you should be sorted

Comment: Thanks jobwat! I could remove the error. But another error came up `Failure/Error: click_on "Lookup" NoMethodError:undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`. I'm looking for a solution, but until now nothing found. I'm going to ask another question if you don't know about this error.

Comment: I added `WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)` to `config/environments/test.rb`, then it works as I expected.